# Autofac Scoping Of Unit Of Work In MVC3 With Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, autofac, unit-of-work

We have a standard "chain" of modules that MVC3 controller creates and calls (directly or indirectly) - "MyController" -> "MyService" -> "MyRepository" -> "MyUnitOfWork"

The modules are registered in App_Start as following:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<MyRepository>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MyUnitOfWork>().AsSelf().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest();

IContainer container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver( new AutofacDependencyResolver( container ) );
```

When we try to perform multiple calls to the service from the controller in parallel, we're getting exceptions in EF4 (we use DbContext as a base class for UoW).

What would be a correct scoping of the modules to make parallel calls to service in the context of the same HttpRequest?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "exceptions?"

Comment: The exceptions are related to the fact that DbContext is not Thread Safe.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like 1 DbContext per HttpRequest isn't gonna work for you. You probably need `InstancePerDependency()` and then request a new DbContext per thread.

Comment: It doesn't work for sure with "InstancePerHttpRequest". 
I'm wondering what Autofac scoping fits best such a scenario.
All the components are "constructor-injected", therefore the scope is set in App_Start.

Probably, I'd rather create a dedicated scope explicitly before calling the service. However it makes the code less maintainable and probably breaks the whole concept of "injection"